# php mysql join 2 tables and get limited rows from each group

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables like category , products. I want to fetch 2 products from each category in single query.

Category table contains the following

```
intCatId    varName

1       cat1

2       cat2

3       cat3
```

======================

Product table

```
intPId    PName  intCatId    

1          pro1       1

2          pro2       1

3          pro3       1

4          pro4       3

5          pro6       3

6          pro7       2
```

I used the following query

`SELECT a.*, b.*  FROM product a INNER JOIN category b ON a.intCatId=b.intCatId  GROUP BY b.intCatId`

```
How to apply limit here.
```

I need the output as

```
intCatId     varName    intPid     PName

1            cat1         1         pro1

1            cat1         1         pro1

2            cat2         6         pro7

3            cat3         4         pro4

3            cat3         5         pro6
```

please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Mysql doesn't support window functions for such type of query like other RDBMS but you can use rank query by using user defined variables

```
select intCatId, varName,intPId, PName,rank
from (
select *, @r:= case when @g = intCatId 
     then  @r + 1
     else 1 end rank,
     @g:= intCatId
    from(
    select c.intCatId,c.varName, p.intPId, p.PName
    from category c
    join product p on c.intCatId=p.intCatId
    order by c.intCatId
    ) a cross join(select @g:=null,@r:=0) t
) t1
where rank <= 2
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d94d/14)

Comment: This query works bu it is returning more than two product for a categor. Add this at the end `GROUP BY rank, intCatId
ORDER BY intCatId`

Comment: @syedsuleman i have already added the [`demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9a75/9) category1 has 3 products but in result set you can see there are only 2 products also group by without using any aggregate function is not a good idea to use please recheck your query other wise you have a demo for working one

Comment: @khalid check this. [Updated Demo][1]


 http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d94d/1  I just added more products and it returns more than two in result.

Comment: @syedsuleman there is some variable initialization issue i ahve updated my answer with updated query [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d94d/14)